# Enumerated table row ID in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's suppose there is a table user

```
id_user | name | id_state

1       | John |   2
```

and a table user_state

```
id_status | description

2         | User Active
```

using Codeigniter, what is the best way to do something related to that id_status, without having integer hardcoded in my code??
example:

```
if($user->id_status == 2){
    // do something
}
```

..

actually i have used in other projects a class to create "enums":

```
Enum::Create('UserState', 'inactive', 'active', 'banned', 'deleted');
```

and them..

```
echo UserState::GetDatabaseID(UserState::active); // result: 2
```

.. and i think it is a good solution, but i have never used it in a Codeigniter project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this user_state table is small enough (i.e. < 10 states) I would consider just putting an array right down in your application. So define some high level property in your My_Model for instance that says:

```
$this->user_states = array(
    'active'=>2,
    'deleted'=>3,
    'new'=>4,
    'verified'=>5
);
```

Then later in your code you just use something like

```
if ($this->id_status == $this->user_states['active']) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make a method in the model that queries both tables and returns an object with the status attribute so you can access the name of the status. I usually create a *name* or *slug* field as a lowercase name with no spaces to reference in my code and a *display_name* field for display in views.

So in your model, do something like this:

```
public function get_user_info($user_id)
{
    return $this->db
        ->select('user.*, user_state.*, user_state.id AS user_state_id') // to avoid a conflicts when referencing the ID
        ->where('id', $user_id)
        ->join('user_state', 'user_state.id = user.id_state')
        ->get('user')
        ->result();
}
```

Then you will have access to `$user->status->slug` in your controller to reference 'active' or whatever status you want, and then `$user->status->display_name` in your views to print out a user-friendly name.

Answer (score 0):

If the user_state table (almost) never changes and only has a few records, you may consider removing it from the database completely and just using config values.